# Writing datagridview data to excel sheet not working vb

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to export my datagridview to an excel sheet using vb. I can save the excel file and name it but I open the excel file, it is blank, only having the sheet name. Here is my code:

```
Private Sub exportDGVToExcel_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim app As _Application = New Application()
    Dim wb As _Workbook = app.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing)
    Dim ws1 As _Worksheet
    ws1 = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    ws1 = wb.ActiveSheet
    ws1.Name = "First Sheet"
    For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1
        ws1.Cells(i, 1) = DataGridView1.Columns(i - 1).HeaderText
    Next i
    For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
        For j As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1
            ws1.Cells(i + 1, j) = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value.ToString()
        Next j
    Next i
    Dim file As New SaveFileDialog()
    file.FileName = "test"
    file.DefaultExt = ".xlsx"
    If file.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
        wb.SaveAs(file.FileName, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing)
    End If
    app.Quit()
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "exportDGVToExcel_Load" handles the Form.Load event.  At this point in the code execution, it is unlikely that `DataGridView1` has any rows or columns especially if you are setting the DataGridView.DataSource property somewhere else.  Set a breakpoint in the method and debug your code.  Inspect the values of `DataGridView1.Rows.Count` and `DataGridView1.Columns.Count`.

Comment: Thanks, I placed the code where DataGridView1 is loaded, and it worked. Would I take the same approach for all the other DataGridViews I have if I want to put them in separate sheets?

Comment: It really depends on how you want the application to work and you have not provide enough information for me to determine that.  Typically, people load a DGV for viewing/editing data.  Exporting the data is typically a user initiated action (i.e. click a button). If you are loading a DGV just for your export code to process, then the DGV could be eliminated at you would export the data directly from the source.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Should be easy to translate to VB. Let me know if you need help.

```
internal  static void ToCSV_File(ref DataGridView dgv, string filename = "")
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        string quote = "\"";

        //Headers
        int i = 0;
        foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in dgv.Columns)
        {
            if (i > 0)
            {
                sb.Append(",");
            }
            sb.Append(quote + col.HeaderText + quote);
            i++;
        }

        sb.AppendLine();

        int r = 0;
        int c = 0;
        foreach (DataGridViewRow dr in dgv.Rows)
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in dgv.Columns)
            {
                if (c > 0)
                {
                    sb.Append(",");
                }

                sb.Append(quote + dr.Cells[col.Index].Value + quote);
                c++;
            }

            c = 0;

            sb.AppendLine();
            r++;
        }

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(filename))
        {
            filename = Path.GetRandomFileName() + ".csv";
            string folder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.InternetCache);

            filename = folder + @"\" + filename;
        }


        File.WriteAllText(filename, sb.ToString());
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(filename);

    }
```